# Angular routing: routes not found after deploy on production server

Tags: angular, deployment, routes, production-environment

After building and deploy my angular 8 project on prod server, I tried to get access to some url like : ***https://serveraddress/admin/*** the server return 404 not found error, this work perfectly on localhost and I cannot catch why this happen ! other routes work except related admin dashboard url doesn't work !

here is my routing file :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component'
import { AuthenticationComponent } from './components/authentication/authentication.component'
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component'
import { TheaterComponent } from './components/theater/theater.component'
import { ShowsListComponent } from './components/shows-list/shows-list.component'
import { GiftChecksComponent } from './components/gift-checks/gift-checks.component'
import { FaqComponent } from './components/faq/faq.component'
import { EspaceadminComponent } from './components/espaceadmin/espaceadmin.component';
import { GestionFaqComponent } from './components/gestion-faq/gestion-faq.component';
import { GestionUsersComponent } from './components/gestion-users/gestion-users.component';
import { GestionCGVComponent } from './components/gestion-cgv/gestion-cgv.component';

import { AuthGuard } from './_shared/_guards/auth.guard'
import { GestionGiftComponent } from './components/gestion-gift/gestion-gift.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'authentication',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,

  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'theater',
    component: TheaterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'shows',
    component: ShowsListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'restaurants',
    component: RestaurantsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'gifts',
    component: GiftChecksComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'faq',
    component: FaqComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'gestionfaq',
    component: GestionFaqComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'CGV',
    component: SellsConditionsComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'shows/search/:key',
    component: ShowsSearchComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'restaurants/search',
    component: RestaurantsSearchComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'shows/:id/details',
    component: ShowDetailComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'restaurants/:id/details',
    component: ShowDetailComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'profile/infoPerso',
    component: PersonalInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile/updatepassword',
    component: UpdatePasswordComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'reservation',
    component: CombinedReservationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile/contermarques',
    component: ContremarquesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile/cheques-cadeaux',
    component: ChequesCadeauxComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile/tableauDeBord',
    component: TableauDeBordComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile/comptefidelite',
    component: CompteFideliteComponent
  }


];

const routesAdmin: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: EspaceadminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin/gestionfaq',
        component: GestionFaqComponent

      },
      {
        path: 'admin/gestionusers',
        component: GestionUsersComponent

      },
      {
        path: 'admin/gestioncgv',
        component: GestionCGVComponent

      },
      {
        path: 'admin/gestionchecks',
        component: GestionGiftComponent

      },

    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), RouterModule.forChild(routesAdmin)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this ?  I'm having the same problem, after deploying my Angular app to Azure.

Comment: am facing same issue. Instead of 404 am getting File not found text on blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error 404 Not Found in Nginx after deployment

Thing is, Angular8+ is a Single Page application.

When you request `yourserver.com/some-page` there is no `<project_root>/some-page/index.html` to serve, hence the 404 error.

What you need to do is, whenever your server hits some page it didn't find, redirect back to index.html, so Angular can take care of it

For **nginx**, on your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<your_site>`:

```
server {

    # other stuff

    # MAKE SURE IT HAS THIS CONFIG HERE:
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

    # other stuff
}
```

For other servers, such as **Apache** please refer to [THIS DOCUMENTATION](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Answer (score 0):

Two basic ways to handle this

1. Add useHash true in routing **"RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})"**
2. add **404.html** page in dist/projectFolder after production build (This works for me.)

Refer https://angular.io/guide/deployment for more details for details regarding deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can read this documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

> Basic deployment to a remote server For the simplest deployment,
> create a production build and copy the output directory to a web
> server.
>
> Start with the production build:
>
> content_copy ng build Copy everything within the output folder
> (dist/project-name/ by default) to a folder on the server.
>
> Configure the server to redirect requests for missing files to
> index.html. Learn more about server-side redirects below (https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback).
>
> This is the simplest production-ready deployment of your application.